# Replace invalid characters with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace invalid characters from filenames with this code:

```
$str="ÁsícáLáÓ Pá LáS NÉnÁ BíÉn HéRéJÉs óézíí";
$count;
$patterns = array('/[áÁ]/', '/[Éé]/', '/[íÍ]/', '/[óÓ]/', '/[Úúü]/',  '/[\s¿<>\?:,\n\r]/');
$replacements = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', '-');
$str = strtolower($str);
$str = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $str, -1, $count);
print_r($str);
echo $count;
```

I don't need to sanitize the input, just replace these chars.

My output is this: `-aasaicaalaaao-paa-laas-naenaa-baiaen-haeraejaes-aoaezaiai`, which adds some 'a's here and there, and sums 43 substitutions. Where are they coming from? That's more than the total number of characters of the string.

Probably, I'm overlooking a very basic functionality of `preg_replace()`, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: You might try `preg_replace(/.../u, ...)` if you are certain everything is utf-8. Otherwise you might have to look into the mb* functions (http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) such as `mb_ereg_replace()`

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
$patterns = array('/[áÁ]/u', '/[Éé]/u', '/[íÍ]/u', '/[óÓ]/u', '/[Úúü]/u',  '/[\s¿<>\?:,\n\r]/u');
```

Hat tip to [Peter Bowers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4282342/peter-bowers)

Answer (score 1):

Have a go with strtr() as well. This is perhaps the "classic" way to solve this problem...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

Answer (score -1):

Don't know why you need regular expressions here.  You could simple use `str_replace()` for this.

```
$replace_map = array(
    'á' => 'a',
    'é' => 'e',
    ...
    ',' => '-',
    "\n" => '-',
    "\r" => '-'
);
$str = str_replace(
    array_keys($replace_map),
    array_values($replace_map),
    strtolower($str)
);
```

Comment: Why downvote?  My guess is that this operation would run more efficiently than using regex.